# Submitting a second form in div with refreshed data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

After submitting a form, the data is posted to an ajax call in jquery.
The data in the form is refreshed, with a different input type and a new submit button.

The first html form:

```
<form id="firstform">
<textarea id="firsttext"></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="firstsubmitbutton" value="send">
</form>
```

Posts to this jquery:

```
$('#firstsubmitbutton').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var cpm = $.trim($("#firsttext").val());
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "result.php",
data:{ myvar: cpm }, 
success: function(data){
    $('#firstform').fadeOut('slow', function() {
       html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
});
```

In result.php the new data to replace the input types is loaded:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='secondformvalue'>";
echo "<input type='submit' id='submitsecondform' value='Send second form!'>";
```

But then this jquery does not respond

```
$('#submitsecondform').click(function(event){
alert('second form posted');
});
```

I can not get the new submit-button to work, because it is not known in the initial load.

What has to be added or written differently to get the second form to work as well? (And a third, fourth, etc.?)

Comment: Where is the `#secondformvalue` declaration/used? Check your console and see what that reveals, as well as PHP's error reporting. I am not a JS guy, but that should help you in a way.

Comment: Not necessary for example. It's used instead of     alert('second form posted');
Your duplication-mark is incorrect. That question is about passing one value to another form, not submitting a new form.

Comment: The 2nd (possible) duplicate I found seems to address this.

Comment: No, I've seen that as well in my search. It's still one form. I'm trying to submit the second form that is loaded from ajax-data after submitting the first.

Comment: I understand. I'm glad to see that the answer provided below was the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the java script is first loaded the form didn't exist thus the `click` event handler couldn't be registered as needed.

To work around this you can register the event on the `body` element instead.

Something like the following should work for your use case:

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitsecondform', function() {
    alert('second form posted');
});
```